# Key dependency in AWS AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

I know we can create an image of the EC2 server by creating AMI of the server.

But there is a  dependency of on the key. I cannot launch my AMI with another key. They AMI can be launched with the original key.

How can I launch an AMI with the some other key?

Also, if there is a key dependency than what if I make my AMI public, how other users will launch the AMI with there  personal keys??

Comment: Can you clarify wich key you are referring to ? Your AWS access key and secret key ? Your ssh key pair ? Also what is the OS ? Windows or Linux ?

Comment: Key pair, Linux system right now I am referring

Answer (score 0):

It's an image of the original EC2 instance. You'd use the same key.

I don't think you can add another key after the fact. You could also create a new AMI with the keys installed that you want to use.

Comment: But what if I dont want to share my key pair with the other user

Comment: Why would you have to? Use the original key, create users that have the  keys that you want, create AMI.

Comment: If some one wants to launch that AMi with his Keys than How it is possible ?? The server will refuse his keys !!! there must be a solution to that

Comment: It won't refuse them if you create a user than has his key.

Comment: I have tested that it desnot pick other key

Comment: You'll need to create a new user for each key. It's an incredibly bad idea to 'share' keys.